# Loadrunner during recording with truclient protocol chrome/firefox instances were opening in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome, protocols, loadrunner, truclient

In Loadrunner Truclient protocol while recording the web application Google Chrome/Firefox instances is opening in incognito mode but the issue is my application will not work incognito mode.

My application is working fine in only normal mode of Google Chrome/Firefox instances.

Could anyone please let me know during recording with truclient how to change the Chrome/Firefox instances from incognito mode to normal mode.

Comment: Based on an answer below, it looks like you have cross-posted this elsewhere, and have not declared the cross-posting either there or here. The result of this is that people may help you in both places, because they are not aware you have already received help. In this fashion, you have not guarded against people having their time wasted, which is not the ideal way to respect the valuable time of volunteers. Please always declare your cross-posting in future, anywhere on the internet.

Comment: (This has been an important part of Netiquette for about 30 years, so it's not like this is a modern idea `:)`).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You already posted this question on the official product forum (https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/Urgent-Truclient-chrome-instance-is-opening-in-Incognito-mode/m-p/1624503) and got a response by the lead developer of the TruClient protocol.

His answer is:

```
TruClient runs the browser in Incognito/Privacy mode to allow separation of 
Vusers during a load test.

This cannot be disabled or changed.

Perhaps you can elaborate on why your application is not working in these 
modes, so we can try to find a workaround.
```

and then

```
Some browser features behave differently in privacy mode.

For example, IndexedDB cache mechanism is not implemented in Firefox 
private mode [See the bug in Mozilla]
```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781982

```
From the error you mentioned, it seems this is related a similar browser issue. 

As mentioned before, it is not possible to run TruClient in non-private mode.
```

Comment: It's very rude to ask the same question in multiple forums.  This creates confusion on the part of those researching similar issues as to which forum is authoritative for responses to a given thread.   This behavior will get you banned from many forums on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Run one full GUI Virtual User in a singular operating system instance.  run one of these per business process on dedicated OS instances.  Run the remainder of your load using API level (HTTP) virtual users.